# Excel history not showing full change

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file saved in a locally-synced O365 directory. I opened it in the Excel for Mac desktop app today, and noticed the data in 3 columns were not in the correct rows.

I know this happens in columns where there is a formula, but none of the cells in any of these columns contained a formula.

When I view the contents of previous versions of the file (i.e. File > Browse File History), I can see that:

- I am the only person who has edited the file
- the last time the file was saved, the data was correct

One column is sorted (text, alphabetically), but I can't recreate any combination of filtering / sorting that results in the view of the data I found when I opened the file today.

I would have expected any changes in filtering / sorting to be reflected in the version history.

Can anyone explain what has happened here? Although I obviously have the data, it did confuse me! It'd be nice to understand the issue, and stop it happening again...

Comment: Do you mean that you opened up a worksheet and found that the data was not in sort order, and that the sort order was the same as when you last closed it?

Comment: @harrymc it wasn't just that the sort order wasn't the same; the order of Column A hadn't changed, but the order of Column B had changed, so that the values in Column B weren't correct for the values in Column A

Comment: Sounds incredible - even impossible. Do you have any installed extensions? Test if this happens when you only run in safe mode by a shortcut with `excel /safe`. If it still happens, uninstall and reinstall Office.

Comment: @harrymc Excel for Mac doesn't have a safe mode. I don't have any extensions installed. The same issue has also happened again in a different worksheet - I know it's difficult to prove and seems (as you say "incredible") but this _is_ what is happening